# Enviar un file con ajax y procesarlo con php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy desarrollando un editor de texto, estoy intentando cargar archivos en vivo, donde tu cargas el archivo y aparece en el editor de texto similar a word, lo estoy haciendo sin un `form` asi que es mas complicado procesarlo con PHP, quiero que al cargar el archivo este inmediatamente lo cargue en el servidor, abrirlo y ejecutarlo en el cliente con `AJAX`

```js
        //INPUT FILE
        $("input[name=loadtxt]").change(function(event){
           $.ajax({
              url:'http://localhost/proyecto_servidor/loadtxt.php?file='+this.files[0],
              method:'POST',
              success:function(data){
                 //response here
              },
              error:function(data){
                  console.log(data);
              }
           });
        });
```

```html
<input type='file' name='loadtxt' accept='.txt' class='firepad-btn firepad-dropdown'>
```

Intente enviarlo por la URL, y llega en PHP como (Object File) pero no se acceder a estas variables que ofrece el archivo file como name,size etc, la idea es que en php, abra el archivo con ese nombre y lo cargue con fopen

Answer (score 2):

No se si una imagen se pueda enviar por url o no, la forma en la que yo siempre he enviado imágenes al servidor es la siguiente:

**En el JS**

```
$("input[name=loadtxt]").change(function(event){
    var file = this.files[0];

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append('file', file);

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/proyecto_servidor/loadtxt.php',
        data: datos,
        method:'POST',
        success:function(data){
            //response here
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**En el PHP**

```
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$ruta_temporal_archivo = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

Te dejo este [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) donde podrás encontrar más información acerca de `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede enviar por url una imagen el punto es almacenar la imagen

```
$img =  file_get_contents($_FILES['aQUI PONES EL ID DE LA IMAGEN DEL FORM']['tmp_name']);
```

de esta manera puedes recuperar la informacion de la imagen